# Работа с ASCII Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, gnu

Меня интересует как в GNU ASM после того, как на вход текста, печаталось с переводом строки в определенное количество символов ( ну к примеру 15 символов в первой, 15 во второй, не считая переноса строки конечно же)

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Совершенно невменяемая формулировка. Если "на вход текста, печаталось" - это ввод с клавиатуры - то перевод строки, введённый нажатием Enter, такой же равноправный символ в потоке символов, как и символ от нажатия любой другой клавиши. Т.е. с точки зрения асма введена ОДНА СТРОКА. Просто при её отображении в местах 0x0D 0x0A надо будет перемещать соотв. образом положение курсора.